# How do I re-point an outside wall?

Tags: walls

How do I re-point an outside wall? What tools and techniques should be employed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to be a bit more specific with your question. But, in general, the tools would be various masonry trowels...specifically one for tuckpointing, a joint striker (to strike the mortar if you want to indent it) and a wire brush.

How to do it? Well, a quick Google should show you plenty of tutorials, but basically you:

1. Chisel/grind out as much loose mortar as you can
2. Mix new mortar (ideally mortar rated for the particular brick you are using)
3. Insert mortar (either via the tuckpointing trowel, or you can use the 'icing bag' technique)
4. let dry a little bit, strike the joints
5. let dry a little bit more, run a wire brush over the brick to clean up an extra